# Drop down menu with action button in PrimeFaces

Tags: button, drop-down-menu, primefaces, action

Using primefaces, how can I implement dropdown list, which immediately fulfills the action to go to the next page?

I have a dropdown list:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="names" value="#{backing.name}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Peter Jan" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Tom Bert" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Magda" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And then press a button:

```
<h:commandButton action="detail" value="View Detail"/>
```

I want this in one action:

Select "name" from dropdown with immediate "button-pressed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with `p:ajax` and a redirect like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="names" value="#{backing.name}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Peter Jan" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Tom Bert" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Magda" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{testBean.goToDetail()}" /> 
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

and

```
public void goToDetail() {
    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("detail.xhtml?name=" + name);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```